# Trying to submit a form after loading it via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm loading a  from a server using ajax, but when I try to submit it, it is never submitted.. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function successHandler (result) {
}

function errorHandler (error) {
}

$.ajax({url: "http://www.****.com/new",
  dataType: 'html',
  beforeSend: function() {
  },
  complete: function() {
  },
  success: function (result) {
  $('#app-status-ul').hide();

  ajax.parseJSONP(result);
  },
  error: function (request,error) {
  alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
  }
});

var ajax = {
parseJSONP:function(data){

$('#movie-data').append(data);

$('#movie-data').listview('refresh');
var newTheme = 'b';
}
}

//HERE I TRY TO SUBMIT THE LOADED FORM
$("form").on('submit', function() {
  alert( "Form submitted" );
});

});
```

As you can guess I expect an alert('Form submited') after submit it.

Comment: move the event handler declaration inside the ajax success function. The way you do it now, Ajax is still loading while the .on() method tries to find the form which is not in the dom yet

Comment: Submit it with javascript (I don't think you can submit a dynamic form) (also required="required" should just be required)

Comment: @user3154108 I have this now:`success: function (result) {       $('#app-status-ul').hide(); ajax.parseJSONP(result);           $("form").submit(function() {alert( "Submited form" ); });` but I still don't see the alert "Submitted form"
        },`

Comment: @dwana I don't have any problem submitting the form if I load it normally (with the rest of the dom elements) instead of using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Jquery function `submit()` (http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

```
$("form").submit();
```

Comment: Can you put your html?

Comment: I finally solved it using `$('#movie-data').on('submit','form',fn`